# Exception thrown when trying to execute query in Java

Tags: java, mysql

When trying to execute the query, it throws a SQLException (Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed).
Connection is established though.

**Code:**

```
public ResultSet executeQuery(String sql, Object... parameters) {
        try (Connection c = dataSource.getConnection(); PreparedStatement stmt = c.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++) {
                stmt.setObject(i + 1, parameters[i]);
            }

            ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery();

            resultSet.close();
            stmt.close();
//            c.close();

            return resultSet;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
        at com.hylexismc.profiles.Main.getProfile(Main.java:127) ~[?:?]
        at com.hylexismc.profiles.Main.hasProfile(Main.java:107) ~[?:?]
        at com.hylexismc.profiles.Main.lambda$onEnable$0(Main.java:50) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_11_R1.scheduler.CraftTask.run(CraftTask.java:71) ~[spigot-1.11.2.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-2b6c9f4]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_11_R1.scheduler.CraftScheduler.mainThreadHeartbeat(CraftScheduler.java:353) [spigot-1.11.2.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-2b6c9f4]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.MinecraftServer.D(MinecraftServer.java:738) [spigot-1.11.2.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-2b6c9f4]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.DedicatedServer.D(DedicatedServer.java:399) [spigot-1.11.2.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-2b6c9f4]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.MinecraftServer.C(MinecraftServer.java:678) [spigot-1.11.2.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-2b6c9f4]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:576) [spigot-1.11.2.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-2b6c9f4]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_131]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964) ~[spigot-1.11.2.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-2b6c9f4]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:897) ~[spigot-1.11.2.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-2b6c9f4]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:886) ~[spigot-1.11.2.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-2b6c9f4]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860) ~[spigot-1.11.2.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-2b6c9f4]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkClosed(ResultSetImpl.java:743) ~[spigot-1.11.2.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-2b6c9f4]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.next(ResultSetImpl.java:6301) ~[spigot-1.11.2.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-2b6c9f4]
        at com.hylexismc.profiles.Main.getProfile(Main.java:115) ~[?:?]
        ... 9 more
```

**Edit 1:**
Now, I have changed it, it gives exactly the same, how does this work?

```
public ResultSet executeQuery(String sql, Object... parameters) {
            Connection c = null;
            PreparedStatement stmt = null;
            ResultSet resultSet = null;

            try {
                c = dataSource.getConnection();
                stmt = c.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

                for (int i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++) {
                    stmt.setObject(i + 1, parameters[i]);
                }

                resultSet = stmt.executeQuery();
                return resultSet;
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(e);
            } finally {
                try {
                    assert c != null;
                    assert stmt != null;
                    assert resultSet != null;

                    c.close();
                    stmt.close();
                    resultSet.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Comment: You need to read the results before you call `resultSet.close()` (and before you call `stmt.close()`); **and** you should be closing both in a `finally` block. Once you close either of those, you can't retrieve any more values.

Comment: I changed it, but I got the same exception, please see the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are closing the ResultSet by calling

```
resultSet.close();
```

After that you are returning the resultSet and you are calling the `resultSet.next()` method. You are not suppose to call the `next` method after closing the `ResultSet`.

For solving this issue close the `ResultSet` after getting the data.

Comment: Alright, that does work.
But wouldn't I ever need to close the connection? I've heard that's best practice.

Comment: You should close `ResultSet`. You can make your method in such a way that it return the required data and not the `ResultSet`.